# How to create a dynamic query builder in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, query-builder

I had following data `array` which include the details of employees

```
const data = [{
  name: 'Foo',
  age: 32,
  emp_id: 19,
  role: 'Manager',
},
{
  name: 'Foo',
  age: 33,
  emp_id: 23,
  role: 'Developer',
}]
```

I need to perform `array.find` method to find the correct one,Problem is I had all the find criteria as `array`,

```
const criteria = [{
  operator: "equals",
  key: "name",
  value: "Foo"
}, {
  elementOperator: "AND",
  operator: "equals",
  key: "age",
  value: 32
}]
```

find query down below,

```
const filteredData = data.find(c => c.name === "Foo" && c.age === 32)
```

My question how to convert the criteria to query,

```
c.name === "Foo" && c.age === 32
```

Comment: How would `(cond1 || cond2) && cond3` be represented?

Comment: You'll need to write a function which converts things like `"AND"` to `&&`, and `"equals"` to `===`

Comment: It's doable, but it's a big piece of code to do. you want it for free?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't judge me much, this is just a demo of the function dispatch approach. The use of `elementOperator` is not implemented here. But you can extend this approach to your own needs. I hope it helped.

Live Demo:

```js
const data = [{name: 'Foo', age: 32, emp_id: 19, role: 'Developer'},
              {name: 'Goo', age: 33, emp_id: 20, role: 'Manager'},
              {name: 'Eva', age: 34, emp_id: 21, role: 'CTO'},
              {name: 'Roo', age: 35, emp_id: 22, role: 'QA'},
              {name: 'Too', age: 36, emp_id: 23, role: 'QA'},
              {name: 'Noo', age: 37, emp_id: 24, role: 'Developer'},
              {name: 'Moo', age: 38, emp_id: 25, role: 'Developer'}];

const myFilter = (data, criteria) => {
  const predicates = {
    equals: (key, value) => (obj) => obj[key] === value,
    gte: (key, value) => (obj) => obj[key] >= value,
    lte: (key, value) => (obj) => obj[key] <= value,
    localeCompare: (key, value) => (obj) => !obj[key].localeCompare(value, false, { sensitivity: 'base' }),
    includes: (key, value) => (obj) => obj[key].toLowerCase().includes(value.toLowerCase()),
  };

  return criteria.map(({ operator, key, value }) => predicates[operator](key, value))
    .reduce((acc, condition) => acc.filter(condition), data);
};


// --- TEST---
const criteriaToText = (criteria) => criteria
  .map(e =>`${e.key} ${e.operator} ${e.value}`)
  .join(', and ');

let criteria =  [{operator: "equals", key: "name", value: "Foo"}, {elementOperator: "AND", operator: "equals", key: "age", value: 32}];
console.log(criteriaToText(criteria));
console.log(myFilter(data, criteria));

criteria = [{operator: "gte", key: "age", value: 35},{operator: "equals", key: "role", value: "Developer"}];
console.log(criteriaToText(criteria));
console.log(myFilter(data, criteria));

criteria = [{operator: "lte", key: "age", value: 33}];
console.log(criteriaToText(criteria));
console.log(myFilter(data, criteria));

criteria = [{operator: "localeCompare", key: "name", value: "evä"}];
console.log(criteriaToText(criteria));
console.log(myFilter(data, criteria));

criteria = [{operator: "includes", key: "role", value: "er"},{operator: "lte", key: "age", value: 37},{operator: "gte", key: "emp_id", value: 19}];
console.log(criteriaToText(criteria));
console.log(myFilter(data, criteria));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0 }
```

Comment: logically `elementOperator` should be a parent element, not part of each line of `criteria`...